# How can I "tell" my SO account to use the picture of my Gmail account?

Tags: support, profile-picture

I've just asked [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360454/what-are-the-dimensions-of-the-profiles-picture) about changing the picture of my Stack Overflow account, they told me to change the dimensions of the picture, I tried that, and it didn't work. I asked a colleague of mine, and he told that our enterprise doesn't authorize the use of some websites such as "img..." which is used to upload pictures to Stack Overflow. That's why it didn't work for me.

I learned that it's possible to attach the picture of the Stack Overflow profile to the picture of a Gmail account. My question is: How can I attach my Stack Overflow profile picture to my Gmail profile picture so at the end I change the Stack Overflow picture?

PS: I could change my Gmail profile's picture.

---

**EDIT :**

I double checked my gmail account linked to my SO account if it is the correct one, I double checked that my gmail account has an image (maybe I have to have an image on my Google+ account? which I can't access btw due to the policy of my entreprise again!). Then I used the google button to log in as you said @animuson. Plus, I cleared the cash of the browser. Nothing happened! Am I missing something?

[image: My account with out the option to change to google]

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41277/how-do-i-change-my-profile-picture-or-avatar for how to do profile pictures.

Comment: @iBug He’s saying his corporate firewall blocks Imgur. If he uploads his picture manually to SO it will be hosted on Imgur and therefore blocked. He’s hoping there’s a way to have the displayed picture hosted on google, as with gmail, because his corporate firewall permits that. I don’t think that’s possible, but I don’t know the ins and outs of gravatar. Maybe if he changes the image on gravatar.com or something.

Comment: How about uploading using your cellular data?

Comment: @iBug However uploaded, if uploaded to SO, the file will be hosted and reside on imgur.com. Meaning when he opens stackoverflow.com some of the html will look like `href=“...imgur.com/...”`, which, when his browser tries to resolve, his corporate firewall will dutifully block. He’s asking if there’s some supported way that that piece of html read `href=“...gmail.com/...”` (or whatever) instead.

Comment: Maybe the easiest option is to find a new employer that doesn't have those insane firewall policies ...

Comment: @rene xD do you have an idea on a new employer that would employ me?

Comment: @ziMtyth No, I'm sorry but I hear good stories about [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab), assuming you are allowed to visit it from your company network ....

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible. We only look up your profile picture and name at the time of registering your account, and *only* if you're using the Google button and authenticating through their service (not just a Google email and password combination). Registering in this way will cause a Google option to appear in the dropdown when changing your profile picture, assuming you had one set on your Google account. Registering using the Facebook method adds a similar option, allowing you to use the Facebook profile picture.

Note that these pictures *do not update*. It will only ever use the profile picture you had set when you registered (it stores a hard URL to it). So if the service doesn't update the picture at that URL or stops processing requests for it at any point, then your profile picture here will be old or broken with no way of updating it outside of switching to one of the other options we have.

If you didn't register using one of those two services, then there is no way to add them and you are stuck uploading to Imgur or using Gravatar.

Comment: how can I use Gravatar? I've created one but I don't know how to use it in SO